# Git Push Heroku Master error in rubyonrails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

First off there is a lot of other errors I am getting, but I want to start with the lead error.. Ok so i want to push my project to my heroku server. I am in my apps directory and i run 
"git push heroku master" and this is what i get

```
Identity added: /Users/some_ayodele/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/some_ayodele/.ssh/id_rsa)
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 145, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (124/124), done.
Writing objects: 100% (145/145), 31.06 KiB, done.
Total 145 (delta 27), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.5.2
       New app detected loading default bundler cache
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (>= 0) more than once.
       You should probably keep only one of them.
       While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
       Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (>= 0) more than once.
       You should probably keep only one of them.
       While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
       Your Gemfile lists the gem jquery-rails (>= 0) more than once.
       You should probably keep only one of them.
       While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
       You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * carrierwave
       * rmagick
       * heroku
       * git-rails
       * hoe (~> 1.5.1)
       * RedCloth
       * i18n
       You have deleted from the Gemfile:
       * thin
       Bundler Output: Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (>= 0) more than once.
       You should probably keep only one of them.
       While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
       Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (>= 0) more than once.
       You should probably keep only one of them.
       While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
       Your Gemfile lists the gem jquery-rails (>= 0) more than once.
       You should probably keep only one of them.
       While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
       You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * carrierwave
       * rmagick
       * heroku
       * git-rails
       * hoe (~> 1.5.1)
       * RedCloth
       * i18n

       You have deleted from the Gemfile:
       * thin
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:desolate-temple-6370.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:desolate-temple-6370.git'
```

Comment: Do you have the `pg` gem listen multiple times in your Gemfile?

Comment: No, it was listed once in 
gem 'pg'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think Postgres is the issue here. I believe Heroku and Rails builtin PG causes some issue. Try editing your gem page like this:

```
group :development, :test do
     gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
     gem 'pg'
     gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Then, do "bundle install".

If this doesn't work try doing "bundle install --without production"

Hope this helps.

Comment: So i did what u advised and then "bundle install" and I get the following "Fetching gem metadata from 
An error occurred while installing rake (10.1.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.1.1'` succeeds before bundling."

Comment: It works now, bundle install gave me errors because I did not add my gemfile.lock file to my repo, once i did bundle install worked like a charm. I then removed  gem 'pg' from my gemfile since it is already mentioned in 
group :production do
     gem 'pg'
     gem 'rails_12factor'
end

and all is fine now thanks!

Comment: but one more issue, it is pushing to heroku alright but when i go to the url it says The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.???